# Use Powershell and Regex to match only the first one

Tags: powershell

in my device config it has the show running-config and start-up config which both are configured with line vty the same such as

```
show running-config

line vty 0 4
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10

start-up config
line vty 0 4
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10
 transport input ssh
```

I wrote the Powershell script and regex below and when I ran the script it output four times.  I want to match only the first match and output just the result from the running-config but don't know how.  can someone help pls?

```
$Line_VTY = Select-String -path c:\test\config.txt -Pattern "\sline\svty\s\d{1}\s\d{1,2} -Context 0,6

write-host $line_vty
```

and the output shows

```
line vty 0 4
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10
 transport input ssh
line vty 0 4
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 access-class 20 in
 password 7 373737
 login authentication test
 exec-timeout 10
 transport input ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

Select string is going to match everything, to get the first, pipe it to `select-object`

```
select-object -First 1
```

something like

`Select-String -path ./config.txt -Pattern "\sline\svty\s\d{1}\s\d{1,2}"  | select-object -First 1`

or with context I get

[image]

Comment: actually I tried that but it didn't work with the switch -context

Comment: That should work, but note that it's simpler and more efficient to use `Select-String -List`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) offers the `-List` switch, which finds only *1* match per input file:

```
Select-String -List -Path c:\test\config.txt -Pattern '\sline\svty\s\d{1}\s\d{1,2}' -Context 0,5
```

Note that you'll receive a single output object with [match information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo):

- The `.Line` property contains the matching line.
- The `.Context` property contains the additional 5 context lines in its `.PostContext` property.

Therefore, if you want to output all 6 lines *individually*, as *strings*, use the following:

```
Select-String -List -Path c:\test\config.txt -Pattern '\sline\svty\s\d{1}\s\d{1,2}' -Context 0,5 |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Line; $_.Context.PostContext }
```